# How do I access the media settings

Tags: php, theme-development

I have been trying to find a way to access the the maximum width of a large image as set on the media settings page?  In my theme I am grabbing images from a server and have the ability to specify the size when I grab them.  I want to grab the image with the width set for the large image size on the media settings page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sizes are stored in the options table in the database, so you can grab values with `get_option('large_size_w');`

The values stored in the DB are:

- thumbnail_size_w
- thumbnail_size_h
- medium_size_w
- medium_size_h
- large_size_w
- large_size_h